# In Powershell, how to I extract only the 7-digit numbers from email subject-lines?

Tags: powershell

Here is my Powershell code :

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$sentMail.Items | % { $_.TaskSubject | Select-String -Pattern '\d{7}' }
```

So this will print all the email subject lines containing a 7-digit string. However, I want to *only* print the 7-digit string in these lines.

I should use `match` , I believe. But match returns true/false ? What is the way to go about it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"\d{7}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value} }
```

Comment: this works, but when it outputs it then it has a bunch of extra new-line characters so it takes long to shoot them out. any way to keep them all in one-quick line?  thanks so much !!

Comment: I've changed the script to only show the one's that matched.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering myself, because I just figured one way to do so:

We need another pipe ( `|` ) , and in this we use the `match` command:  like so -

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $_.TaskSubject | Select-String -Pattern '\d{7}' 
                                     | % {([string]$_) -match '\d{7}' | out-null;                                     $matches) }
```

This prints out :

```
Name                   Value
-----                  -----
0                      8293798
0                      8233798
0                      1223798
..etc etc..
```

But this is 2 columns, I'd want just 1 column